# How to add properties in the end of the two first lines with double quote?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed, perl

We want to add the following properties:

```
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M
```

in the two first lines that contain the word - `HBASE_MASTER_OPTS`

*Example before change*:

```
more ams-hbase-env-template.txt

export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"    
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=71 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=72 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=73 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"
```

*Example after change (expected results)*:

```
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M"    
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=71 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M"
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=72 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS=" -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=73 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"
```

What I did until now is that:

```
sed -i '/HBASE_MASTER_OPTS/ s/$/-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M/' ams-hbase-env-template.txt
```

But this isn't right because:

1. We want the properties before the end of double quote.
2. Properties must be only on the first two lines that variable is HBASE_MASTER_OPTS.
3. **In case properties are already in line, then it will not append again on any next time!**

Comment: Your point 3 is not fully clear to me: Do you mean that if a line contains HBASE_MASTER_OPTS, but also already contains the properties, you do not want to add them again?  And, if such a line is encountered, would it still count as being one of the first two lines?

Comment: regarding to Your point 3 is not fully clear to me: Do you mean that if a line contains HBASE_MASTER_OPTS, but also already contains the properties, you do not want to add them again  - YES I  MEAN THAT

Comment: @yael Can you update your example (before + after) so that your point 3 is covered? It would be helpful if your example would reflect all the points that you need on what you're asking... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending on Steve's answer:

```
awk '/HBASE_MASTER_OPTS/&&/ -XX:[+]UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M/{x++;print;next}/HBASE_MASTER_OPTS/&&x<2{gsub(/"$/," -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M\"");x++}1' ams-hbase-env-template.txt
```

Update: Here's a more maintenance friendly version, where every string only occurs once.

```
awk 'BEGIN{p="-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M"}{m=0}/HBASE_MASTER_OPTS/{m=1;++x}m&&index($0,p){print;next}m&&x<=2{gsub(/"$/," " p "\"")}1' ams-hbase-env-template.txt
```

And some explanation:

- In the first version in the pattern matching, `[+]` is used for the literal + character, because otherwise `+` would be interpreted as special character.

The remaining points are about the second version:

- In the `BEGIN` clause, the properties string `p` is defined.  All the following clauses apply to the lines of the input.
- `{m=0}`: This clause has no condition, which means it applies to every line, such that for each line first `m` (for match) will be set to zero.
- `/HBASE_MASTER_OPTS/{m=1;++x}`: If a line matches the `HBASE_MASTER_OPTS` string, `m` is set and our line counter is incremented.
- `m&&index($0,p){print;next}`: this clause checks if, in addition to a match indicated by `m`, also the properties string is contained in the input line.  In such a case `index` will return an non-zero value.  If so, we print the line as it is (not adding the properties again) and with `next` skip the remaining clauses and start processing the next line.  Note that the following clauses were originally provided by Steve and only adapted by me:
- `m&&x<=2{gsub(/"$/," " p "\"")}`: if we reach this point and we have a matching line and our counter has not exceeded 2, we modify `$0` (the input line) by prepending the terminal `"` with a blank and our properties string.  Apart from that, no output is produced, which will be done by the next clause.
- `1`: This is a condition (always true) without an action, which means the action defaults to printing the input line.

Comment: it still append the properties even if they are exist in the lines

Comment: ok I will wait for the fix

Comment: what to say , wonderful really ,

Answer (score 3):

How about this `awk` solution.  Creates the desired output in the question.

```
awk '/HBASE_MASTER_OPTS/&&x<2{gsub(/"$/," -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M\"");x++}1' ams-hbase-env-template.txt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9f38PJMdg13tcxOMQ1KN4/ICRYX02twsaoOr24NElDX0lFX0dJQTciwko7tDjV3dknP90tMyc1KL8ksSQzPw8s41eam5Ra5J8Gly22NQVLwAWCM6tSbY18Y5SUNK0rtLVrDf//T60oyC8qUcCw3RZim7NvsGdeZkkm0Ja8dP/k5NKCxLzkSreixGSQtbbmBnA3YVfpn5dTqcTFRaEthnSxxYguthgTYwsA)

Comment: one problem is that when we run your CLI , let say we put the output to out.txt , on the next time awk will append the lines , so actually we get duplicate properties

Comment: so can you fix the awk syntax , so on the next awk running it will not append the properties because they are already exists